# Query takes too long because of <> in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I'm building a script to send by email. I've a table with transactions and I want to send by email only when status is "failed" . The table has now ~ 50 millions of rows and it will keep increasing and I cannot archive it.

this is the query:

```
if exists (select top 1 1 from TicketTransactionDetails where ServiceStatus != 0)
begin
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;  
  
    SET @tableHTML =  
        N'<H1>Transactions Status</H1>' +  
        N'<table border="1">' +  
        N'<tr><th>TransactionDate</th><th>NbOfRecords</th>' +  
        N'<th>ServiceStatus</th><th>StatusDescription</th><th>RunDate</th></tr>' +  
        CAST ( (select  td = CAST(InsertDate as date), '',
                        td = COUNT(*),'',
                        td = ServiceStatus,'',
                        td = b.StatusDescription,'',
                        td = GETDATE() 
            from TicketTransactionDetails a 
            inner join ServiceStatuses b on a.ServiceStatus = b.StatusID
            where ServiceStatus = 0
            group by CAST(InsertDate as date),ServiceStatus,b.StatusDescription
            order by CAST(InsertDate as date) desc 
                  FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE   
        ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +  
        N'</table>' ;  

        exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @profile_name = 'DB_Maintenance',
        @recipients = 'a.a@a.a',
        @subject = 'Tranzanctions with errors',
        @body = @tableHTML,  
    @body_format = 'html';
end
```

What takes a lot to execute (~ 25sec) is:

```
select top 1 1 from TicketTransactionDetails where ServiceStatus != 0
```

Is there way to improve my query?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to provide your table definition, your index definitions and the execution plan (using "paste the plan") for performance advice.

Comment: If you don't have an index on ServiceStatus definitely start there, you could also try to replace your != comparison with a greater than comparison, assuming this works with the ServiceStatus values. Queries using 'not equals' can be quite slow.

Comment: The right index is likely all you need. And in fact SSMS might even suggest it to you.

Comment: Your code seems flawed to me. You first check for `ServiceStatus != 0` but your query filters for `ServiceStatus = 0`.

Comment: "Tranzanctions" != "Transactions" in the language I use.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you can do -

Firstly, check whether you have an index on the column `ServiceStatus`. If not then create it. That really ought to do it.

The other option, although **risky** is to add a (**nolock**) hint to your query. This will bypass any locks held on the table

`select top 1 1 from TicketTransactionDetails (nolock) where ServiceStatus != 0`

Comment: Using `nolock` for a message queue sounds like a very bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. There is no index on the column. I'll see with the index how it works, i would prefer indeed not to use nolock

Comment: If you *are* recommending `NOLOCK` as well, you should be highlighting all the consequences of using such a hint has as well so that the OP doesn't get any nasty surprising when the data they get isn't the data they expect.

Comment: Do **NOT** recommend [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: i've put an index and not it works perfect. thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Use count instead, count perform much better than top

```
if exists (select count(1) from TicketTransactionDetails where ServiceStatus != 0)
```